# Cannot recieve DATA from RESTFUL API using IONIC 2 generated provider

Tags: json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

So, i'm currently studying Ionic 2 to make hybrid applications. I'm following a course on Udemy but the course's content about HTTP requests to WEB API's is obsolete(it's from the ionic 2 Beta). This is a long question but some of you's who are more experienced on the Ionic 2 framework can just skip to step 8 to save some time. Thanks a lot guys!

I'm trying to retrieve data from this URL:

> https: //viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/.

**It has a space after https:// because stackoverflow won't allot me to post more than one link.**
But I'm missing something to save this data on a variable I created.

What I did to this point is:

1) I generated the provider which I called ConnectionService using the CLI ionic generator.

```
ionic g provider ConnectionService
```

2) Created a method called getCEP() inside the ConnectionService Provider, which makes an **HTTP GET Request**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the ConnectionService provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class ConnectionService {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello ConnectionService Provider');
  }

  getCep(): Promise<Response>{
      let response: any = this.http.get("https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/");
      console.log("Response: " + response);
      let responsePromise: any = response.toPromise();
      console.log("ResponsePromise: " + responsePromise);
      return responsePromise;
  }
}
```

**P.S.: Here you can see i'm loggin in two steps of the request: The first one is the response before I turn it into a Promise, so I can return it to the page. The second one is after i cast it to a Promise using the toPromise() method.**

3)In my view I have a button which has the (click) directive calling the method buscarCEP()

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Teste</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <button (click)="buscarCep()">Request CEP</button>

</ion-content>
```

4.1) My TypeScript file has imported the ConnectionService Provider and named it ConnectionService.

4.2) I declared the ConnectionService inside the @Component directive under the "providers:" label

4.3) I create an instance of Connection Provider that I call conServ on the constructor's declaration. Also I created a variable called CEP, to store the data that I pull from it.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ConnectionService } from '../../providers/connection-service';

/*
  Generated class for the MenuTest page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-menu-test',
  templateUrl: 'menu-test.html',
  providers: [ConnectionService]
})
export class MenuTestPage {
  public CEP: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public conServ: ConnectionService) {
  }
```

6)Then I modify the method buscarCEP() so that it gets that conServe instance and calls the getCEP() method which makes an HTTP Request to the URL given above.

```
buscarCep(): void{
    this.conServ.getCep().then(data =>{
      console.log("DATA:" + data);
      this.CEP = data;
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("ERRO: " + err);
    });
    console.log("CEP: " + this.CEP);
  }
```

**PS.: As you can see, i'm logging three steps into the request: The data when the getCEP() method executes, a possible error called 'err' and by the end of it, the variable CEP that I created before and saved the data value to.**

7)When I run the application and click on the button, I get the following screen with the console.logs:

Image of ionic page with snips of the Chrome console
[image: Image of ionic page with snips of the Chrome console]

8) As you can see, my logs are returning as follows:
8.1) The "Hello ConnectionService Provider" is from the console.log inside the provider's constructor, so the import of the provider is fine and it is being instantiated.
8.2) the "Response: [object Object]" is from the first console.log() inside the getCEP() method in the provider itself.
8.3) the "RespondePromise: [object Object]" is from the second console.log() inside the getCEP() method in the provider itself, after i casted the response to a Promise.
8.4)"CEP: undefined" comes from the console.log inside the buscarCEP() method, which is called after I click on the Request CEP Button
8.5)"DATA:Response with status: 200 OK for URL: https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/" comes from the console.log() inside the buscarCEP() method.

9) From this i'm taking that the getCEP() method is being able to connect to the URL, hence why the Response and ResponsePromise logs have an Object attached to them. Also the DATA log tells me that i recieved an OK Response from the server. My question is in regard to CEP: Undefined log. I can't seem to store that object in the variable I created.

I know that this is a long one but I wanted to lay all my cards on the board and explain everything as thoroughly as I could because i'm new to this framework.

Any help is appreciated, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Response object` *is* stored in `this.CEP`. The issue is `console.log(this.CEP)` is called *before* the response from the HTTP request is returned within `then`.Promises are asynchronous.You can check the contents by doing `console.log(this.CEP)` within `then`.
So if you were to print the data in the html side, use safe navigation operator `?`. e.g: `{{CEP?.property}}`.

A couple of issues with your code:

1. You should extract the json data from your response object. I suggest you do:
   `this.CEP = data.json();`
2. If you want to print the contents of the object you can try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,2))`.

Comment: oh ok got it, that's also why the DATA: log with the 200 OK is coming after. will try it now, thanks a lot